# ExtJs data binding for dynamically generated button based store data

Tags: extjs, extjs6

Will extjs buttons created from looping over store data have data binding or not. If not how can we achieve data binding in such case. 
Need help. Thanks

Json

> {success:true,
>
> data:[{id:'1',label:'new'},{id:'2',label:'save'} ] }

Part of ViewController

```
this.getViewModel().data.storedata.load(function(records){ 
  Ext.each(records,function(record){
     this.view.add({
          xtype:'button', 
          id:record.get('id'),
          text:record.get('label')
      });
   });
 }
```

Comment: can't you do it on store load?

Comment: If I do it in store load will that have two way data binding.